# How do I construct a random sample from a subdivided population?

Tags: python

Suppose there are 1000 people and they are all asked if their favorite meal is breakfast, lunch, or dinner. I store that info in a list like:

```
mylist = [350, 450, 200]
```

i.e. 350 people like breakfast, 450 like lunch, 200 like dinner.

How do I randomly sample 100 people and get a similar list back? That is I want to get randomly sampled lists like

```
[35, 45, 20]
[33, 42, 25]
[37, 46, 17]
```

Thanks..

EDIT: I want to add one thing. The desired behavior is sampling without replacement. Suppose that, following the above example, I want to sample 999 people from the original 1000. It shouldn't be possible to get a list back that is, for instance, `[350, 458, 201]`, because there aren't 201 people who like dinner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
import numpy as np
res=np.random.choice(350*[0]+450*[1]+200*[2],size=100,replace=False)
np.histogram(res,range(4))[0]
```

And more generally:

```
import numpy as np
v=[350,450,200]
res=np.random.choice(np.repeat(range(len(v)),v),size=100,replace=False)
np.histogram(res,range(len(v)+1))[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this without replacement is to draw random integers between 1 and 1000 (representing people) without replacement and then determine which bucket they fall in (the breakfast, lunch, or dinner group):

```
import numpy

vec = [350, 450, 200]

# pick people without replacement
samp = numpy.random.choice(1000, 100, replace=False)

# get their preference
prefs = numpy.digitize(samp, numpy.cumsum(vec))

# count people by preference
numpy.histogram(prefs, 3)[0]
```